# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') - axios post nodejs jest

Tags: node.js, axios, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test for axios post request using jest.
This is my actual fucntion -

```
exports.getAccessToken = function (urlToCall, scope, basicAuthToken) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let axios = require("axios");
    let qs = require("qs");
    let data = qs.stringify({
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      scope: scope,
    });
    let config = {
      method: "post",
      url: urlToCall,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: "Basic " + basicAuthToken,
      },
      data: data,
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(
          "error occurred while getting access token for the scope - ",
          scope,
          " and the error is - ",
          error
        );
      });
  });
};
```

This is my unit test code -

```
const processUtils = require('../src/utils/process-utils')
const axios = require('axios')
jest.mock("axios")
describe("when getAccessToken API is successful", () => {
    test('should return access token', async () => {
        const expectedResponse = JSON.stringify({
            "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMxZDY2OTF",
            "issued_token_type": "token-type:access_token",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "expires_in": 3600,
            "scope": "consumer_profile:read:"
        })
        axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(() => Promise.resolve(expectedResponse))
        // axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(expectedResponse));

        let urlToCall = 'https://somehost.com/access_token/v1'
        let scope = jest.fn
        let basicAuthToken = jest.fn

        const response = await processUtils.getAccessToken(urlToCall, scope, basicAuthToken)

        expect(mockAxios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(urlToCall)
        expect(response).toEqual(expectedResponse)
    });
});
```

This is the error thrown while running jest -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

> axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
       resolve(response.data);
    })
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZiVp.png
I am new to node and jest. Can someone point me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Having the `require`s in the exported function is quite unusual, I'm not sure how it behaves. Have you tried placing them outside of the `exports`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that your code is not directly invoking the `post` function on the `axios` module instance and is instead doing it implicitly via the `config`, whereas your test mock is looking for a direct `axios.post` call. There are 2 ways you can resolve this problem.

1. Change an implicit `post` call into an explicit one:

From:

```
axios(config).then(function (response) {
```

To:

```
axios.post(config.url, config.data, { headers: config.headers }).then(function (response) {
```

This will use the result of the `axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce` call.

2. Mock out the axios post call in the test suite set up:

From:

```
jest.mock("axios")
```

To

```
jest.mock("axios", () => {
  const expectedResponse = JSON.stringify({
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMxZDY2OTF",
    "issued_token_type": "token-type:access_token",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "consumer_profile:read:"
  });
  return () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(expectedResponse));
})
```

This will mock out the implicit `post` call via a **partial** mock, however you will not have direct access to the `post` method, hence you will not be able to listen to its calls.

Another small note, `axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(() => Promise.resolve(expectedResponse))` will pass a function into the `response` argument when `then` is called. I think what you need to use `mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(expectedResponse)`. Additionally, `expectedResponse` should be wrapped in a `data` property as follows:

```
const expectedResponse = JSON.stringify({
  "data": {
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMxZDY2OTF",
    "issued_token_type": "token-type:access_token",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": "consumer_profile:read:"
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've made two changes - 
changed implicit post call into an explicit one and Mock out the axios post call in the test suite set up. Somehow it is not mocking and giving 'undefined' response as shown below with the test output -

Expected: "{\"access_token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMxZDY2OTF\",\"issued_token_type\":\"token-type:access_token\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"scope\":\"consumer_profile:read:\"}"

Received: undefined

Comment: If you are making an explicit call (number 1), you do not need to do the test suite set up (number 2), that was an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My issue got resolved. The issue was my actual method was already returning promise but my mock method also had promise object returning.
Instead of return () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(expectedResponse));
I'm returning return expectedResponse;

Comment: Good stuff, would you mind accepting this answer if it helped you in resolving the original problem in the question. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to post the solution so that it helps someone.
Solution was found based on Ovidijus Parsiunas responses too.
Actual function:

```
exports.getAccessToken = function (urlToCall, scope, basicAuthToken) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let axios = require("axios");
    let qs = require("qs");
    let data = qs.stringify({
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      scope: scope,
    });
    const requestHeaders = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: "Basic " + basicAuthToken,
    };
    // axios(config)
    axios
      .post(urlToCall, data, {
        headers: requestHeaders,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(
          "error occurred while getting access token for the scope - ",
          scope,
          " and the error is - ",
          error
        );
      });
  });
};
```

My unit test case:

```
const processUtils = require('../src/utils/process-utils')
const axios = require('axios')
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn(() => {
    const expectedResponse = {
      access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMxZDY2OTF",
      issued_token_type: "token-type:access_token",
      token_type: "Bearer",
      expires_in: 3600,
      scope: "consumer_profile:read:",
    };
    // return () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(expectedResponse));
    return expectedResponse;
  }),
}));
describe("when getAccessToken API is successful", () => {
  it("should return access token", async () => {
    const expectedResponse = {
      data: {
        access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMxZDY2OTF",
        issued_token_type: "token-type:access_token",
        token_type: "Bearer",
        expires_in: 3600,
        scope: "consumer_profile:read:",
      },
    };

    axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce(expectedResponse);

    let urlToCall =
      "https://somehost.com/access_token/v1";
    let scope = jest.fn();
    let basicAuthToken = jest.fn();

    const response = await processUtils.getAccessToken(
      urlToCall,
      scope,
      basicAuthToken
    );
    console.log("response - ", response);
    expect(response).toEqual(expectedResponse.data);
  });
```